# How to calculate conditional probability based on a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, probability

I used r to generate a 5*5 matrix [(Table 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oUDl.png).

```
# rm(list = ls())
set.seed ( 2022 ) 
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1,25,replace=T), ncol = 5)
rownames(mat) <- c ("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5")
colnames(mat) <- c ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

The rows represent regions, and the columns represent whether the regions (0/1) exported products, and now I need to calculate the conditional probability [(Table 2 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkHVc.png) of exports between products through this matrix, for example, in the case of export B, the probability of export A [P(A|B)=P(AB)/P(B)] or in the case of export A, the probability of export B [P(B|A )=P(AB)/P(A)]. Because there is only R1 for exporting A and B at the same time, P(AB)=1 [ignoring the denominator, actually considering the number of regions exporting A and B at the same time], there are 2 regions (R1, R3) for exporting A, and 4 for exporting B. A region (R1, R2, R4, R5), so P(A|B)=1/4, P(B|A)=1/2 (part of [Table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFYld.png)).
The three tables are combined as shown in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npvez.png).

This work is an intermediate process of calculating an indicator, but r is very new to me, so now I am facing the problem of how to write code to calculate the conditional probability, I hope to get your guidance, thank you all.

Comment: This looks like homework material. Could you just give us the desired output with everything computed?

Comment: Using `condprob` can solve this problem

Comment: If your problem is solved, either post the answer and accept or delete the question. (Answering your own question is encouraged in the FAQ!)

Answer (score 0):

Using `condprob` can solve this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).